# hide submit button after clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a table with several rows, which by clicking on submit button on each row, the information on each table will send to ajax, and will insert to database. after it clicked,I need to hide the button from table. How can I reach to this mission? 
here are my codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform<?php echo $y; ?>").validate({
            debug: false,

            submitHandler: function(form) {

                $.post('process.php', $("#myform<?php echo $y; ?>").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results<?php echo $y; ?>').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

My form:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform<?php echo $y; ?>" action="" method="POST">  
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name<?php echo $y; ?>" size="30" value=""/>  
<input type="image" name="submit" id="accept<?php echo $y; ?>  " value="Submit" src="graphics/accept.png"> 
</form>

<div id="results<?php echo $y; ?>"><div>
```

Comment: Why don't you show old plain html, without php at all? php changes nothing in this question and only makes noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to hide button only then you can use.

```
$.post('process.php', $("#myform<?php echo $y; ?>").serialize(), function(data) {
      $('#results<?php echo $y; ?>').html(data);
      $('#accept<?php echo $y; ?>').hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,but where should I have to put it exactly? It's not working

Comment: code might now work because in your form code see that extra space after id `id="accept<?php echo $y; ?>  "` getting remove it for like `id="accept<?php echo $y; ?>"` then try again

Answer (score 1):

Use `.hide()` on your button e.g. `$("#mybutton").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) . In your case `$("#mybutton").hide()`